# How to create an object while using enum in a class?

Tags: java, class, object

I previously have the variable `availability` stored in a double which is present inside a class named `wrapper` as below -

```
public final class Wrapper {

private final double availability;


Wrapper(){
this.availability = 2;
}


public Wrapper(final double availability){
this.availability = availability;
}

public double availability (){  // Need a confirmation if this is a getter ?
return this.availability;
}
}
```

Now, I have to change the scenario a bit by making availability as an object.Reason being - **Now we want availability per region** unlike the above case.Also, we need to use that availability object inside the `wrapper` class now.

Here is what I'm trying to do -

```
public final class Availability {
public enum Region {
US,
UK,
EU;

private final double availability;

Region () {
this.availability = 2;
}

Region (double availability) {
this.availability = availability ;
}
}
```

I'm supposed to use the Availability object inside wrapper class as wrapper class object is being used in other places which previously used to take argument (Availability). Now I don't want to break that workflow. Also I'm a bit confused a bit regarding creation of object for `Availability` class as I'm using an enum. Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not deface your question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per my understanding, you do not need `class Availability`.

Define `Region.java` file as having `public enum Region`, then you can have that constructor along with adding a missing getter.

```
public enum Region {
    US(2),
    UK(2),
    EU(2);

    private final double availability;

    Region (double availability) {
        this.availability = availability ;
    }

    public getAvailability() {
        return this.availability;
    }
}
```

Then `Wrapper` can accept `Region` instance instead, and access `.getAvailability()` method of it.

```
public final class Wrapper {

    private final Region region;
    
    public Wrapper(Region region){
        this.region = region;
    }
    
    public double getAvailability() {
        return this.region.getAvailability();
    }
```

e.g. `System.out.print(new Wrapper(Region.US).getAvailability());`

Comment: Thank you so much for this. So, the default value 2 goes as argument for each enum ? But not asa constructor?Also, the getter mentioned above "getavailability" gets us the value of availability per region?

Comment: I dont think you can overload enum constructors. Therefore, you need the parameter arguments on each

Comment: Thank you, so this (value=2) serves as a default value for all the regions now?

Comment: It's a static value. IMO, calling it "default" would imply it can be overriden.

Comment: Ya, I mean. Initially all the regions availability will be set to =2. But later they can be overridden with a different value right?

Comment: They cannot be changed without re-compiling the code since there is no setter and it is a final variable. You also cannot introduce a new Region or override any at runtime since that's how enums work

Comment: I have a doubt regarding the equals method too which is being used in wrapper class. i have updated the question. Can you pleaseee take time in helping me with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248886/discussion-between-hrx-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: @hrx Please create a new post for new questions