# Came across this enum and have questions about objects and enums in general

Tags: java, object, enums

I have a the following code for setting up availability per region -

```
enum Region {
    UK,
    US,
    EU;
    private final double availability;

    Region() {
        this.availability = 1;        //constructor 1
    }

    Region(double availability) { //constructor 2
        this.availability = availability;
    }

    public double getAvailability() { //getter
        return this.availability;
    }
}
```

I'm writing test cases for the above code to test the constructors as below -

```
@Test
void testConstructor1() {
assertEquals(1, Region.UK.getAvailability())
}
```

I'm confused how to write the test case for second constructor as enums cannot have objects created like classes.

```
@Test
void testConstructor2(){
HERE WE CANNOT CREATE AN OBJECT TO PASS THE VALUE THE TEST CONSTRUCTOR 2 RIGHT?
```

How can I solve this?

If it's a class we can simply create object and pass in the value and test it.

Please take time in answering the questions below -

1. Can enums have objects created like classes?
   2.Is there any alternative way that can be achieved similar to objects?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like something worth testing the way you've done it. It'd be one thing to ensure all of the constants haven't changed (e.g. comparing the #getAvailablility with a map of known values), but as is you're just testing (individually) that a number you put in is the number you got out, which is essentially coupling for change. With an enum, you wouldn't really test the constructors, but the content of it.

Comment: Delete 2nd constructor..or use it ;)

Comment: @xerx593 So, enum can have only one constructor ? But I want the default value at first as well as the user given value when they don't like default value.

Comment: This isn't worth testing at all. Test the code that uses it and this will get covered.

Comment: Here's the previous similar question: [How to create an object while using enum in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74106627/522444), but it was posted under a different user ID and was posted yesterday. Why use a new ID?

Comment: no, it can have many (constructors), but the only ones you (normally) use (besides aop & reflection hacks) are the ones inside body! :) (and you used only `UK, US, EU` (equivalent to `UK(), US(), EU()` ..you could (e.g.) also do: `UK, US(3.0), EU(2.0)` (without hacks!?) there won't be any more Regions created (until a new version is compiled)..so the constructors "de facto private"

Comment: And here is another more recently asked and deleted question by the same person, again using a different user account: [How to create objects for enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130037/)

Comment: Please do not deface your question after asking. This is not allowed, especially if the question has received answers.

Comment: That is irrelevant. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. You waste our time when you vandalize questions as this will be noticed, identified, and reverted.

Comment: Honestly. Sorry for that. Will keep this in mind and act accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

The enum constants `UK`, `US`, `EU` ***are*** objects of the enum `Region`. They are created by calling the parameterless constructor. You can think of them as static final fields:

```
public static final Region UK = new Region();
public static final Region US = new Region();
public static final Region EU = new Region();
```

So to create more `Region` objects, you can just declare more enum constants. Since you want to test the second constructor:

```
public enum Region {
    UK,
    US,
    EU,

    SOMEWHERE_ELSE(10),
    // think of this as:
    // public static final Region SOMEWHERE_ELSE = new Region(10);

    ANOTHER_PLACE(5);
    // this of this as:
    // public static final Region ANOTHER_PLACE = new Region(5);

    // ...
}
```

Notice that this is the only way to create new objects of enums, which is why a defining property of enum classes is that they can only have a *fixed number* of instances.

Now you can test that the second constructor actually assigned the available correctly by checking `getAvailability`:

```
assertEquals(10, Region.SOMEWHERE_ELSE.getAvailability());
assertEquals(5, Region.ANOTHER_PLACE.getAvailability());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't test it, and you don't need to.  You only need to test code that might get used elsewhere, and enum constructors can't be.

All you need to do is test each enum value to ensure that it has the right values.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "test each enum value that it has right values "?

Comment: So, enum can have only one constructor ? But I want the default value at first as well as the user given value when they don't like default value.

Comment: The user can't give a value.  The only code that can possibly create an enum constant is the enum class itself.  You can have as many constructors as you like, but you can't test any of them -- you can only test the enum constants themselves.

Comment: In the code you've given us, constructor 2 can never be used by anyone ever (unless you change the enum class).  The answer to your question 1 is no.

Comment: So, Do I have to create a class and declare enum Region inside that class and can have multiple constructors?

Comment: Do you want to be able to create other regions besides the UK, US, and EU?  If so, Region must be a class, not an enum.  If not, then why would you need other constructors, if all the possible values of the type have the same availability value?